# Determine three in a row regardless of the board size

Tags: python

I have programmed a program of tic tac toe in python where I use the following code to determine if a row / column / diagonal consists of only ones or twos to determine if any of player one or two have won (I use ones and twos instead of x and o). The problem is that I want the winner to be chosen when there are three in a row regardless of the size of the board and with this code this only works for a board of size 3x3.

```
def check_row(board, player):
    ''' 
    Checks row for a win 
    '''

    return any(all(row == player)
       for row in board)

def check_column(board, player):
    ''' 
    Checks column for a win
    '''
    
    # We use transpose() to be able to check the column by using the definition
    # for check_row
    return check_row(board.transpose(), player)

def check_diagonal(board, player):
    ''' 
    Checks diagonal for a win 
    '''
    
    # We use np.diag() and np.fliplr() to be able to check the diagonals 
    # of the game board
    return any(all(np.diag(board_rotation) == player)
        for board_rotation in [board, np.fliplr(board)])
```

For example, if I choose a board with size 5x5, the winner will be, with this code, when it is five in a row and not three in a row. I use `np.zeros ((board_size, board_size), dtype = int)` to create a game board and I have considered whether you can use something like `column_1 == column_2 == column_3` to determine if there are three in a row:

```
if board[1][1] != 0:
        if board[1][1] == board[0][0] == board[2][2]: 
            return board[1][1]
        elif board[1][1] == board[0][2] == board[2][0]:
            return board[1][1]
```

But also for this to work in a 5x5 game board I have to write down all possible ways to get three in a row in a 5x5 board which will give an extremely long code. Any tips to improve this?

This is my fully code now:

```
''' 403-0047-MPO '''

import numpy as np
import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# scenario = What scenario you would like to play, scenario one or scenario two
# game_size = The size of game board, 3x3, 5x5 or 7x7
# games = The number of game rounds you would like to play
# board = The game board

def create_board(board_size):
    
    ''' 
    
    Creating an empty board 
    
    '''   
    
    return np.zeros((board_size,board_size), dtype=int)

def available_spaces(board): 
    
    ''' 
    
    Looking for available spaces on the game board 
    This is used in both scenario one and two 
    
    '''
 
    lst = [] 
   
    for i in range(len(board)): 
        for j in range(len(board)): 
           
            if board[i][j] == 0: 
                lst.append((i, j)) 
    return(lst)

def make_random_move(board, player): 
    
    ''' 
    
    Randomly places the player's marker on the game board 
    This is used in both scenario one and two
    
    '''
    
    spaces = available_spaces(board) 
    space = random.choice(spaces)
    board[space] = player 
    return board

def available_space_middle(board, board_size):
    
    ''' 
    
    Checks that the center position is available for all game boards 
    This is only used in scenario two 
    
    '''
    
    # Using if-statements to find the middle for all board_size ∈ {3, 5, 7} 
    # and check that they are empty, this also avoids placing the marker there repeatedly.
    
    lst = []
    
    for i in range(len(board)): 
         for j in range(len(board)): 
             
             if board_size == 3:
                 if board[i][j] == 0: 
                     lst.append((1, 1)) 
             if board_size == 5:
                 if board[i][j] == 0: 
                     lst.append((2, 2)) 
             if board_size == 7:
                 if board[i][j] == 0: 
                     lst.append((3, 3)) 
    return(lst) 

def make_move_middle(board, player, board_size):
    
    ''' 
    
    Places the first marker for player one in the center of the game board. 
    This is only used in scenario two 
    
    '''
    
    # Using player = 1 we define that the first move in scenario two should be 
    # made by player one using the marker 1
    
    player = 1
    selection = available_space_middle(board, board_size) 
    current_loc = random.choice(selection) 
    board[current_loc] = player 
    return board

def check_row(board, player):
    
    ''' 
    
    Checks row for a win 
    
    '''
    
    return any(all(row == player)
       for row in board)

def check_column(board, player):
    
    ''' 
    
    Checks column for a win
    
    '''
    
    # We use transpose() to be able to check the column by using the definition
    # for check_row
    
    return check_row(board.transpose(), player)

def check_diagonal(board, player):
    
    ''' 
    
    Checks diagonal for a win 
    
    '''
    
    # We use np.diag() and np.fliplr() to be able to check the diagonals 
    # of the game board
    
    return any(all(np.diag(board_rotation) == player)
        for board_rotation in [board, np.fliplr(board)]) 

def evaluate(board): 
    
    '''
    
    Evaluates the game board for a winner
    
    '''
    
    # Here we bring out the winner and define 1 for when player one wins, 
    # 2 for when player two wins and -1 for ties.
    
    winner = 0
   
    for player in [1, 2]: 
        if (check_row(board, player) or
            check_column(board,player) or
            check_diagonal(board,player)): 
              
            winner = player 
           
    if np.all(board != 0) and winner == 0: 
        winner = -1
    return winner

def play_game(scenario, board_size):
    
    '''
    
    Defines the game for scenario one and scenario two
    
    '''
    
    # By using if-statements and a while-loop we define how the game should
    # go in scenario one and scenario two respectively. 
    # By using break, we also ensure that the loop (game) ends if a winner has been found.
    
    board, winner, counter = create_board(board_size), 0, 1
                
    if scenario == 1:
      
        while winner == 0: 
            for player in [1, 2]:
                board = make_random_move(board, player)      
                # Remove the hashtags below to check the game board step by step 
                print("Board after " + str(counter) + " move") 
                print(board)  
                counter += 1
                winner = evaluate(board) 
                if winner != 0: 
                    break 
        return winner
    
    if scenario == 2:
      
        while winner == 0: 
            for player in [2, 1]:
                board = make_move_middle(board, player, board_size)
                board = make_random_move(board, player) 
                # Remove the hashtags below to check the game board step by step 
                print("Board after " + str(counter) + " move") 
                print(board)  
                counter += 1
                winner = evaluate(board) 
                if winner != 0: 
                    break 
        return winner
    
def save_stats(games, scenario, board_size):
    
    '''
    
    Saves data from all game rounds
    
    '''
    
    # By using the previously defined 1,2 and -1 we add one point for each win 
    # for player1wins, player2wins and ties.
    
    player1wins=0
    player2wins=0
    ties=0 
    
    for game in range(games):
        result=play_game(scenario, board_size)
        if result==-1: ties+=1
        elif result==1: player1wins+=1
        else: player2wins+=1

    return [player1wins, player2wins, ties] # for returning
            
def print_stats(games, scenario, board_size):
    
    '''
    
    Presents data from all game rounds
    
    '''
                        
    player1wins, player2wins, ties = save_stats(games, scenario, board_size)
                            
    print('Player 1 wins:',player1wins)
    print('Player 2 wins:',player2wins)
    print('Tie:',ties)
                     
    # Data
    height = [player1wins, player2wins, ties]
    bars = ('Player 1', 'Player 2', 'Tie')
    y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))
             
    # Create bars and choose color
    plt.bar(y_pos, height, color = (0.5,0.1,0.5,0.6))
             
    # Limits for the Y axis
    plt.ylim(0,games)
             
    # Create names
    plt.xticks(y_pos, bars)
             
    # Saves a pdf with data
    plt.savefig('utfall.pdf') # Saves the data as 'utfall.pdf'
    plt.close()
    

def main():
    
    '''
    
    This is the main body of the program
    
    '''
    
    # Using try: and except: to raise ValueError and 
    # while-loops to handle incorrect input. The question will be asked again
    # if the input value is wrong and continue via break if it is correct.
    
    try:
    
        while True:
            games = int(input("How many games do you want to simulate? "))
    
            if games <1:
                print('The number of game rounds should be grater than zero, try again')
            else:
                break
        
        while True:    
            board_size = int(input("How big playing surface (3/5/7)? "))
            
            if not (board_size == 3 or board_size == 5 or board_size == 7):
                print('Board size does not exist, try again')
            else:
                break
    
        while True:
            scenario = int(input('What scenario (1/2)? '))
    
            if not (scenario == 1 or scenario == 2):
                print('Scenario does not exist, try again')
            else:
                break
    
        print_stats(games, scenario, board_size)
        
    except ValueError:
        print('All questions must be answered correctly for the game to start, try again')
        
main()
```

Comment: What have you tried, or what ideas to you have for extending your code to support larger board sizes?  Seems you could change your existing code to look for 3 in a row instead of "all" in each row you're already checking.  Then you'd just have to deal with the "other diagonals" if you wanted to catch wins there.  I'm not sure how you'd do that using the matrix ops you're using now.

Comment: "Is there any way" is a non-issue for Stack Overflow. Since you're on a general-purpose computer that is barely short of a Turing machine, the answer is almost always "yes". The follow-up question, "How do I do it?", is too broad for Stack Overflow.  Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I agree with Prune. Try some things, possibly with the hints I gave you above, and then come back with some new code to ask us about if you can't fully figure it out.

Comment: Hi, I have now updated my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will post a idea using numpy.split

1. You split your board in chunks of 3, but starting in different positions: 0, 1 and 2.

   Explanation: Consider [a,b,c,d,f,g]
   Starting from 0 -> [a,b,c], [d,f,g]
   Starting from 1 -> [b,c,d]
   Starting from 2 -> [c,d,f]
   so, all possibilities are there
2. You check if the elements are equal 1 or 2 and sum over the boolean mask. If the sum is 3, then there is a chunk with 3 equal elements.

Example code to search from winners on the rows:

```
import numpy as np


#random array just for test
board = np.array([[1,-1,-1,-1,1,0],
                 [1,1,0,1,1,0],
                 [1,1,0,1,1,0],
                 [1,1,0,1,1,0],
                 [1,1,0,1,1,0]])

winner = None

#iterate on i to start from position 0, 1 and 2
for i in range(3):
    #We want the lengh of the array a multiple of 3, so we must correct were it ends:
    rest = -(board[:,i:].shape[1]%3)
    if rest == 0:
        #0 would return a empty list, so if it is the case, we will change to None
        rest = None
    #Now, we calculate how manny divisions we need to get chunks of 3 (on the rows)
    n = (board[:,i:].shape[1])//3

    #Now divide the board in chunks
    chunks = np.split(board[:,i:rest],n,axis = 1)

    for matrix in chunks:
        #sum over all rows of 3 elements
        sumation = np.sum(matrix == 1,axis = 1)
        if 3 in sumation:
            winner = 1
        sumation = np.sum(matrix == 2,axis = 1)
        if 3 in sumation:
            winner = 2
```

Well, maybe a little confusing, but i believe it will work, or at least give you some idea